# What's needed to get a Bill Lumbergh hat?

Tags: support, winterbash

> answer 5 questions on Saturday (in UTC time), not necessarily all on the same Saturday
>
> You haven't earned this hat on any sites yet.

Yet, I see 5 answers on Saturday UTC (I'm assuming "Z" stands for Zulu so that should track with UTC requirement):

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76258/976 - `2014-12-20 02:00:31Z`

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76731/976 - `2014-12-27 15:44:10Z`

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76745/976 - `2014-12-27 21:04:01Z`

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76744/976 - `2014-12-27 20:39:57Z`

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76742/976 - `2014-12-27 20:34:06Z`

Comment: * coughs * hat-whore...

Comment: @Richard - if gods didn't mean for us to earn hats, they wouldn't create them

Comment: I'm wondering quite how far you'd go for a hat. I reckon it's disturbingly far...

Comment: @Richard - One of the Secret Hats involved sacrificing lizards at the door of Stack Exchange office.

Comment: You've already got nearly twice as many hats as anyone else on SciFi; why do you need more?

Comment: @randal'thor - [Because they are there](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/George_Mallory)

Comment: And **here we go again...** :-D

Comment: @randal'thor - eh?

Comment: @DVK Hats, hats, glorious hats.

Comment: @randal'thor - there's no Lubergh hat this time?

Comment: @DVK Not as far as I know. I was more referring to the comment thread here, and our collective hat-whorery ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that there may be a hidden requirement of non-zero (or higher) scores, as theorized here: [Bill Lumbergh - all 5 questions in a single Saturday?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245836/bill-lumbergh-all-5-questions-in-a-single-saturday).

One of those 5 answers is at 0 upvotes, one at 1 upvote.

I'll test that theory by posting an awesome (or at least non-sucky) answer next Saturday and seeing if the very first upvote gets me the hat.

Comment: Did you post the answer? Did you get the hat?

Comment: @Daft - yes/yes    .